# Is it necessary to apply mean-subtraction on FC7 features of an CNN before feeding into L-SVM?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I want to use AlexNet off-the-self features to train an L-SVM on my own dataset. I found that it is recommended to zero-mean features before feeding them into SVM classifier. I just want to know whether it is necessary to do so when using CNNs features or not, since in the first data layer of an CNN, mean-subtraction is once applied on raw input images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not necessary** to subtract mean from FC7 features before using them in to train SVM, but it would not hurt. I'm not exactly sure what L-SVM is, but this answer should hold for any SVM if the data is *"somewhere around zero"*.

On the other hand, it is a good idea to **normalize** the feature vectors (FC7 activations) to **unit length** (e.g. divide them by their L1 or L2 norm). Such normalization often improves classification results, and it makes tuning of SVM hyperparameters much easier.

The decision how to normalize FC7 activations should not depend on the mean subtraction of input images in any way. The input mean subtraction possibly improves training of the network, but it should not affect what the network computes when fully trained. Keep in mind that the image mean is constant and computed on the training set - it affects all images in the same way.